# Azure B2C Password Reset policy in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, forgot-password

I am not getting right way to implement/handle call backs on forgot password policy for Azure B2C.

I have already created json file in raw folder and also added the same schema and data values in manifest.xml

And also when I got error code AADB2C90118 I am handling following code,

var sampleApp = PublicClientApplication(act, R.raw.msal_config)

After loading its not happening any thing, I am not able to understand which callbacks I have use to handle this.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. it's always a good idea to include as much detail (as is needed) to your question :) please add more info to your question, include your existing code and anything else you think is relevant _into_ your question

Comment: Here is my manifest
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="auth"
                    android:host="pakcage name"
                    android:path="redirection-uri"
                    />
            </intent-filter>